# How can I back up my LiveJournal Posts?

Tags: blog, backup, livejournal

I have a free LiveJournal account. I know that at one time there was a way for free users to back up their Livejournal posts, but can't seem to find a way now.

What tools or utilities will allow a free Livejournal user to backup their posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had reasonable luck with [LJArchive](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ljarchive/) in the past.

Answer (score 1):

[The LiveJournal Backup Toolkit](http://www.thejackol.com/2004/05/29/the-livejournal-backup-toolkit/) looks nice.